# Hierarchical select - Save term lineage option creates 2 nodes

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

Hello good people of drupal community!

I'm working on a project which includes Make/model hierarchy of car manufacturers. So my idea was to create a taxonomy vocabulary with all the models under appropriate make, and then to use [Hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module when adding new content to select first make and then appropriate models.

I have Hierarchical select set to "Save term lineage" since I need both make and model to show in node, however, for example if I select "Alfa Romeo" as car make and "Gulietta" as model, Drupal will create 2 nodes instead of one. One node gets created for the make and other node gets created for the model.

Does anyone know how to save the term lineage in one node with both make and model, without separating it in 2 nodes? Big thanks and best regards.

Comment: Are you sure that drupal will create two nodes instead one? If you're creating a node, only one node should be created, no matter what.

Comment: @Jack-PL After diggin in i figured out that actually one node i created but it is displayed 2 times in all of my views for some reason. One node is displayed as make and the other node is displayed as model of the car. 
Cant figure it out why tho, views should display one node remembering both make and model, intead of displaying it in 2 separate nodes.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details about your view configuration. I think the problem is right there.